# Centering images in nivo slider

Tags: javascript, css, slider, nivo-slider

So, Im using nivo Slider in a div with the width set to 100%

The slider works great but the images do not center because the javascript always sets background-position to "initial initial".

I've forced the div, the css to "center center" but the javascript change it every time.

I looked for the tag in the JS Code but i didnt find it

Can someone give me a little help?

Thank you

EDIT: I want this because the images have words and in the lower resolutions i need them in the same spot that in high resolutions

Comment: If get the quick answer from stackoverflow people, you need to provide the code snippet :)

Comment: Please show some code or possibly a jsfiddle. Ta

Comment: The code I add was: 

slider.addClass('centerIt');

.centerIt
 {
 background-position:center center !important;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Add the important property:

```
background-position: center center !important;
```

Comment: I tested your answer, in theory that would do the trick mate but no luck, the images are still aligned to the left.